# Sending modals data in a channel with pycord

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, pycord

i'm trying to do a suggestion modal in a cog for a pycord discord bot, but I want to send the datas of the modal then I get an error (like always)...

```py
class SuggestModal(Modal):
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        self.title = "New suggestion:"
        self.bot = bot
        self.add_item(InputText(label="Username", placeholder="e.g: Wumpus#0000"))
        self.add_item(
            InputText(
                label="Your suggestion",
                placeholder="What should we do for the bot?",
                style=discord.InputTextStyle.long,
            )
        )

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Your Modal Results", color=discord.Color.random())
        embed.add_field(name="Username", value=self.children[0].value, inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Suggestion", value=self.children[1].value, inline=False)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Just sent the suggestion!",embed=embed)
        channel = await self.bot.get_channel(ID_HERE)
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Results", color=discord.Color.Blue())
        embed1.add_field(name="Username", value=self.children[0].value, inline=False)
        embed1.add_field(name="Suggestion", value=self.children[1].value, inline=False)
        await channel.interaction.response.send_message("New suggestion!",embed=embed1)

class Utilities(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.today_time = self.time.strftime(" • Aujourd'hui a %I:%M %p")

    @slash_command(name="suggest", description="Send a suggestion!")
    async def suggestion(self, ctx):
      suggest = SuggestModal()
      await ctx.interaction.response.send_modal(suggest)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Utilities(bot))
```

**ERROR:**

**discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bot'**

(The command is a slash command)

Comment: Please add the code where you send the modal.

Comment: I will add it now

Answer (score 1):

You didn't to pass the `bot` parameter to the **init**() method of SuggestModal.

```py
@slash_command(name="suggest", description="Send a suggestion!")
async def suggestion(self, ctx):
    suggest = SuggestModal(self.bot)
    await ctx.interaction.response.send_modal(suggest)
```

Comment: Now ..... discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'SuggestModal' object has no attribute 'children'

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeError: 'SuggestModal' object has no attribute 'children'` error is because you have to initialize the parent class

```
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        super().__init__(title="New suggestion:")
```

Comment: and another but thanks : await channel.respond("New suggestion!",embed=embed1)
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'respond'

Answer (score 0):

> and another but thanks : await channel.respond("New suggestion!",embed=embed1) AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'respond' – user18180682

I think you need to write `ctx.channel.send(embed=embed1)`

Im not 100% sure, but you should try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).